# How to wrap text without spaces in DataGridView (vb.net / c#)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, word-wrap

I have already set the `DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True`

But this `WrapMode` does not wrap columns with single word without spaces. Is there any way we can "break-word" along with `WrapMode`? Or any other solution?

Comment: I have faced the same problem! No solution yet!

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I ended up not using DataGridView. We are using a paid grid for a lot more reasons such as Printing Capabilities, Summary Facilities, Filters, inbuilt search etc

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the `CellPainting` event.

The `DrawString` respects the bounding `Rectangle` and wraps wherever it hits the right boundary.

You can uncomment the condition to apply only to cells which go over a limit you set.
For best control you would have to measure the length of the `FormattedValue` to find out the exact limit.

You may also want to fine-tune the draw position, if you have special alignments in your cells.

```
private void DGV1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == null) return;
    if (e.FormattedValue.GetType() != typeof( System.String) ) return;
    bool selected = (e.State & DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) 
                            == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected;
    string s = e.FormattedValue.ToString();

    //if (s.Length > 20) // Apply to all or only those breaking your limits
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, selected);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s, DGV1.Font, selected ? 
                   SystemBrushes.HighlightText : SystemBrushes.ControlText, 
                   new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.X + 1, e.CellBounds.Y + 2, 
                                 e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 4));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Setting the `Row.Heights` is up to you. If you go for measuring the `FormattedValue` you will get a `RectangleF` back; so you'll also know the necessary `Height` for that `Cell`. Comparing it to the current `Row.Height` you could gradually adapt it for each `Row`, i.e. make it larger each time it is necessary.. I didn't include, because it will result in Rows with varying Heights and that may be unwanted/unnecessary in your case. If you're interested, I can post the code, though..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

hi Shimply Add following Line after DataBinding

```
DGLogs.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode=DataGridViewTriState.True;

set
AutosizecolumnMode=AllCells
AutosizeRowMode=AllCells
```

in Property windows

Output will be as hown belo Image
[image]